# Overlay shapefile data with polygon shapefile

Tags: shapefile, polygon, r, overlay

I would like to add the overlapping data of a worldwide shapefile, to the different European nuts3 regions (polygon shapefile). However, there is something wrong with the script below as it does not work on the shapefiles that I am using.

```
### download the files available through this link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By9u5m3kxn9yUy1xVDF2NV9TajA

#set your working directory
nuts <- readOGR(".", layer = "NUTS_RG_60M_2010")
grid <- readOGR(".", layer = "a3_mean_annual_runoff_1950_2000")


#projectstring?
#Do I have to do something here to make sure the projections are fine?

#then:
library(raster)
new_spdf <- intersect(grid,nuts) # (this normally works but it does not with these files?

grid_nuts <- gIntersects(new_spdf,nuts,byid = TRUE)
#Take all the values in a particular NUTS polygon, multiply by each the areas of the 
#corresponding new grid cells then divide by the total area of the NUTS polygon

#Added the if statement to avoid non-overlapping NUTS polygons

for(i in 1:length(nuts)){
  if(any(grid_nuts[i,])){
    nuts@data$average_spatial_value[i] <- mean(new_spdf@data$value[grid_nuts[i,]]*
                                                 gArea(new_spdf[grid_nuts[i,],])/
                                                 gArea(nuts[i,]))
  } else {
    nuts@data$average_spatial_value[i] <- NA
  }

}
```

***EDIT : I installed the latest version of R (see sessionInfo() below). The error message I receive is the following:

```
> new_spdf <- intersect(grid,nuts)
Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td, unaryUnion_if_byid_false,  : 
  TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point 13.3081265 48.608032999999999 at 13.3081265 48.608032999999999
In addition: Warning message:
In intersect(grid, nuts) : non identical CRS


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rgeos_0.3-21 raster_2.5-8 rgdal_1.1-10 sp_1.2-3    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1     Rcpp_0.12.7     grid_3.3.1      lattice_0.20-33
```

Comment: I have a completely different setup than yours - so this may not apply (R version 3.3.1, x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, OS X 10.11.6). However I also experienced that R crashed whenever I used the `intersect()` function. Updating to the newest version of `rgeos` (3-21) fixed that problem.

Comment: I installed the latest version of R. I now receive the following error message:
> new_spdf <- intersect(grid,nuts)
Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td, unaryUnion_if_byid_false,  : 
  TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point 13.3081265 48.608032999999999 at 13.3081265 48.608032999999999
In addition: Warning message:
In intersect(grid, nuts) : non identical CRS

Not sure if this should be a separate question now. I'll edit my system info above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I asked a different question specifically to solve a self-intersection error. It turned out that that was the answer to the question. The new question (and therefore also the answer to this question) can be found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216095/r-self-intersection-error-when-using-intersect-with-two-shapefiles).